# Unhandled rejection MongooseError

Tags: node.js, reactjs

dev
configuring db in development mode
connecting to -> NaN
Unhandled rejection MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "number". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (E:\reacttut\reactdemo\eSponsors-master\eSponsors-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:694:11)
at E:\reacttut\reactdemo\eSponsors-master\eSponsors-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:351:10
at E:\reacttut\reactdemo\eSponsors-master\eSponsors-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
at Promise._execute (E:\reacttut\reactdemo\eSponsors-master\eSponsors-master\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:384:9)
at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (E:\reacttut\reactdemo\eSponsors-master\eSponsors-master\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:518:18)
at new Promise (E:\reacttut\reactdemo\eSponsors-master\eSponsors-master\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:103:10)
at promiseOrCallback (E:\reacttut\reactdemo\eSponsors-master\eSponsors-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (E:\reacttut\reactdemo\eSponsors-master\eSponsors-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1149:10)
at Mongoose.connect (E:\reacttut\reactdemo\eSponsors-master\eSponsors-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:350:20)
at Object.connectDb [as dbConfig] (E:\reacttut\reactdemo\eSponsors-master\eSponsors-master\lib\config\dbConfig.js:28:14)
at Object. (E:\reacttut\reactdemo\eSponsors-master\eSponsors-master\server.js:21:8)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem is solve because .env file is missing.

export const url = 'http://localhost:8080'  use your port number

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You probably used a `number` instead of a `string` in `mongoose.connect()` [method.](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) **Check for missing quotation marks or one of them.** Also you can check your credentials in `mongodb`.
Below example code from `mongoose` docs.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?options...');
```